# What's a non-British synonym for a "one-off meeting"?

Tags: synonyms

A "one-off meeting" is a meeting that happens only once, i.e. doesn't reoccur. I read on [macmillanthesaurus.com](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/us/one-off) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220219235507/https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/us/one-off)) that *one-off* is British English. What's a non-British synonym for a "one-off meeting"?

---

[image]

Comment: *One-off* appears in American Heritage Dictionary, and it is natural and idiomatic to this American.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a fairly common term in English even as an AmE speaker, so it should be fine to use. You could also say “one-time.”

Comment: But doesn't "one-time" refer to something historical. Eg. *Harold Wilson, one-time Prime Minister of Britain, is a typical case in point.*  (Even though HW was PM more than once).